# Why is not SignalR.Redis available on NuGet?

Tags: redis, nuget, signalr

first of all this is my first question and I want to follow rules, but if I made a mistake, I am apologize :) My problem is that I want scale-out my website, which using SignalR and I wanted to download SignalR.Redis from NuGet. But it says that there is nothing like this but I found some tutorials witch talking about support for Redis in form of mentioned package on NuGet. I looking on internet for the reason of missing package, but I didn´t find any information about that. Or am I doing something wrong?  Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SignalR Redis is not currently available.  The beta for 1.1 will be coming out soon which will have the Redis scaleout package.

Comment: And can you specify the time horizon of days, weeks or months in which will this beta comes available if you have this information, please?

Comment: The beta package is now available.